# ORMLite exception : java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet already requested

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite

In one of our Java app we have a SQLite DB and multiple threads read and write to the same DB (different tables). These multiple threads however use the same database connection object (ORMLite's DaoManager.createDao()).

We are getting this SQLException (Resultset already requested) randomly whenever some insert/update statement is executing. Below is the stack trace of one such instance.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object ABCD-164: INSERT INTO `pos_order` (`bill_number` ,`order_status` ,`order_type` ,`payment_mode` ,`reference_bill_number` ,`table_selected` ,`sub_total` ,`discountable_sub_total` ,`total` ,`total_discount` ,`discount_type` ,`discount_value` ,`total_tax` ,`service_charge` ,`service_tax` ,`vat` ,`delivery_charge` ,`packaging_charge` ,`amount_paid` ,`waiter` ,`delivery_boy` ,`order_source` ,`delivery_source` ,`card_type` ,`card_name` ,`client_creation_time` ,`client_updation_time` ,`order_comment` ,`customer_feedback` ,`is_deleted` ,`payment_status` ,`pos_outlet_id` ,`is_sync` ,`delivery_status` ,`shipment_id` ,`response_code` ,`delivery_time` ,`custom_packaging_charge_enable` ,`custom_delivery_charge_enable` ,`receipt_printed` ,`total_person` ,`order_origin` ,`json` ,`oo_system_id` ,`pre_order` ,`pre_order_time` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:135)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:450)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:310)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:336)
    at com.limetray.pos.dbmanagers.implementations.PosOrderDaoImpl.insert(PosOrderDaoImpl.java:50)
    at com.limetray.pos.controllers.BillingSectionController.lambda$10(BillingSectionController.java:808)
    at com.limetray.pos.utilities.SingleTaskExecutor$1.call(SingleTaskExecutor.java:37)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet already requested
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.getResultSet(JDBC3Statement.java:136)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:69)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3DatabaseMetaData.getGeneratedKeys(JDBC3DatabaseMetaData.java:1796)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.getGeneratedKeys(JDBC3Statement.java:346)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.insert(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:173)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:91)
    ... 13 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if DaoManager.createDao() is thread safe, please check maybe on thread is asking for data while another already in the data fetch process

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, we are not using createDao() from inside the thread, but only using it to execute queries from the thread.

Answer (score 3):

> In one of our Java app we have a SQLite DB and multiple threads read and write to the same DB (different tables).

With the SQLite database, you can only have one connection to it at a time.  The database has internal locking that ensures that no two threads are using the same connection at the same time but that doesn't stop the DAOs from allowing  multiple threads to cause problems like you are having.

> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet already requested`

In your case, because multiple threads are using the same connection, this exception is getting thrown when one thread asks for results on a connection that has already been asked my another thread.  Their queries are improperly being interleaved.

It's important to realize that this has nothing to do with the underlying database.  Sqlite has its own locking that blocks concurrent access by multiple threads.  But in this case, we are having problems with multiple threads using the same connection.

Right now ORMLite does not have a `ConnectionSource` that provides a `synchronized` single connection to the underlying database so you will have to do your own external locking.  You could extend the [`JdbcSingleConnectionSource` class](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcSingleConnectionSource.java) and use a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) to enforce the controls.  Maybe something like:

```
public class LockedJdbcSingleConnectionSource extends JdbcSingleConnectionSource {

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    // called from JdbcSingleConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection() ...
    public DatabaseConnection getReadWriteConnection() {
        lock.lock();
        return super.getReadWriteConnection();
    }

    public void releaseConnection(DatabaseConnection connection) {
        super.releaseConnection(connection);
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gray! I am calling "DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, cls);" to create a connection (DAO) object every time a query needs to be executed. "connectionSource" here is "SingleConnectionJdbcConnectionSource" as you mentioned and "cls" is the Model class name (different for different model classes). I am still getting all sorts of weird exceptions like "generated-id key was not set by the update call" and "SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state" etc.

Comment: The only change I did is in "SingleConnectionJdbcConnectionSource". Instead of using lock I added synchronized keyword in all the methods. The reason being when I was using lock somehow the app was stuck at some point (may be trying to get a lock already held by some other thread).

Comment: Hrm.  I'm not sure that works @Rahul.B because you need the lock established at the get connection and released at the release connection.  Just making it synchronized doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Gray! I appreciate all of your responses because I understand that you would be busy with your other important work and still find time to respond to my queries. Thanks a lot! I will play with the code today again and update. Once I make it work I would post the code here so that it would be helpful for other people who would face similar types of issues.

Comment: "SingleConnectionJdbcConnectionSource" worked however it started creating another problem wherein sometimes locks are not getting released by some threads and other threads (UI thread) waiting for the lock is stuck. I am thinking of creating some DB cache (An unbounded queue) which would make sure that only one write query is executed at a time that probably would solve the issues with concurrent writes and locks. However, there as well I would need some prioritization in terms of what writes should happen first. What's your thought?

Comment: SQLite doc says that it executes on "Single-Thread", "Multi-Thread" and Serialized mode, wherein Serialized mode is the default. Moreover, In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction. If this is true then I shouldn't have faced issues at the first place? There is another WAL mode (https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) which seems another possibility?

Comment: "Safely used by multiple threads" does _not_ mean that multiple threads will be concurrently able to operate.  It may just be talking about its internal locking.  The error that you are seeing indicates that all of your threads are using the *same connection* and that their JDBC calls are interleaving.  You need to block that.  Either SQLite allows multiple connections or you need to have the locking I've described @Rahul.B.

Comment: Got it. So using multiple connections (using JDBCConnectionPool source) would be better because SQLite would make sure that no concurrent writes are happening?